# Converter for rich:comboBox. What if string representations of enities can contain duplicate elements?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

For example I have PersonEntity and want to use it in rich:comboBox. I must specify converter for this entity (otherwise toString of PersonEntity will be used). PersonConverter return firstname and lastname - "John Smith" and there can be many persons with same name and surname, so converter's getAsObject method will fail to distinguish them and wrong enity will be choosed.
So, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot do anything as soon as they are strings.

You could modify your `getAsString` method to either add a unique identificator to each string e.g. the database PK like [*firstname lastname id*] or detect duplicates and then add an increment only to duplicates such like:

*[John Doe]*

*[John Doe (2)]*

*[Arthur Miller]*

Then you have to ensure that your `getAsString` and `getAsObject` database queries give result sets in the same order.